# C++ - 2D Z-sorting across multiple vectors of objects

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to figure out a way to draw multiple vectors of objects in the right order visually. I understand how to sort the vector based on a point to make things look about right, but how can I do this across multiple vectors? Storing all of the different types of objects in one vector seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Make an index (linking each object's z-order to that object's location), then sort the index

Comment: im not sure what you mean by index.

Comment: Like the index in the back of a book. "Duck, 24. Cow, 26. Goose, 32. Horse, 37".  Etc. Then you sort the index and run through in the order you want to draw objects, e.g. in the above case you'd draw Horse then Goose then Cow then Duck.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single vector that contains pointers to the elements in the other vectors, and then sort *that* vector (using a dereferencing comparitor of course)

```
template<class comparitor>
struct deref_comparitor {
    deref_comparitor(comparitor comp={}): comp(comp) {}
    template<class pointer>
    bool operator()(pointer left, pointer right) {return comp(*left, *right);}
private:
    comparitor comp;
};


std::vector<T*> thingies = {....};
std::sort(thingies.begin(), thingies.end(), deref_comparitor<std::less<T>>());
```

Hmm, I wonder if something like this is already in the standard library?

See it working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ed0015a7535b236

Comment: I'm a little new to C++. Most of of this is going over my head.

Comment: @EvanWard: Alright, does the first sentence make sense to you?  If so, you should be able to figure out _most_ of the last two lines of my code.  You don't necessarily have to understand how `deref_comparitor` works.